# How to convert datetime.timedelta to number? Field 'days' expected a number but got datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, timedelta

My code:

```
data.days=(form.cleaned_data['checkout'] - form.cleaned_data['checkin'])
```

The error message:

```
Field 'days' expected a number but got datetime.timedelta
```

Answer (score 1):

`timedelta` has a `days` property you can use:

```py
data.days = (form.cleaned_data['checkout'] - form.cleaned_data['checkin']).days
# Here -------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.timedelta` is an object instantiated, besides the standard constructor way, as a result of the difference between two datetime objects. It represents a time duration expressed in days, seconds and microseconds.

`timedelta` also provides a set of properties to access those values, namely:

```
timedelta.days
timedelta.seconds
timedelta.microseconds
```

the first one being the one you're searching for.

Comment: how can i use it (timedelta.days) in my code

Comment: data.days = (form.cleaned_data['checkout'] - form.cleaned_data['checkin']).days